# When is the category of connective objects a topos?

Tags: higher-category-theory, topos-theory, stable-homotopy

There is only one stable $\infty$-topos, namely the trivial category. However, the theory of stable $\infty$-categories with $t$-structure is strikingly reminiscent of the theory of topoi, as both have theories of connectivity and truncation; and, moreover, these theories are formally very similar. For the category of spectra with the Postnikov $t$-structure, these theories are related by the fact that the category $\operatorname{Sp}_{\geq 0}$ of *connective* spectra is a topos, and then the two factorization systems coincide.

My question is this: how does this nice relationship generalize when we replace spectra with a more general stable $\infty$-category with $t$-structure? An accessible stable $\infty$-category, say, or a presentable one. Moreover, do we get something nice if we also assume that the $t$-structure is compatible with sequential colimits?

I know that there is at least one positive answer to this question: if we take a category $\mathcal{C}$ which is stable, presentable, and generated by a single compact object, then (applying Dugger's characterization of presentable cats as combinatorial model cats) it is a theorem of Schwede and Shipley that it is equivalent to the category of modules over some associative ring spectrum. Then the usual $t$-structure gives the correspondence we want.

EDIT: As noted in the comments below, this is not a topos. I have asked a corrected and more detailed version of this question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421886/unifying-the-n-truncation-factorization-system-in-a-topos-with-the-n-truncat).

Comment: Connective spectra do not form a topos. For example they are pointed, and their category of discrete objects is abelian

Comment: Ah, how could I have missed that? I mixed up topoi with categories admitting truncation factorization systems. I think I should either rewrite this question or ask a new one. Probably the latter.

Comment: Btw "connective parts of t-structures" are exactly "prestable" categories - you can have a look at Lurie's treatment of those in SAG if you're interested ! I don't think he deals with factorization systems therein, though

Comment: I have asked a corrected and more detailed version of this question at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421886/unifying-the-n-truncation-factorization-system-in-a-topos-with-the-n-truncat.