# Unifying the $n$-truncation factorization system in a topos with the $n$-truncation factorization system of a t-structure

Tags: higher-category-theory, topos-theory, stable-homotopy

(This is a corrected and more detailed version of an [earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421860/when-is-the-category-of-connective-objects-a-topos).)

In good circumstances, e.g. the setting of an $\infty$-topos, we have for each $n\geq -1$ an orthogonal factorization system giving the "$n$-truncation factorization"; that is, there are functors $\tau_{\leq n}:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}_{\leq n}$ which are left adjoint to the inclusions. This notion of truncation is defined by saying an object $X$ is $n$-truncated if $\mathcal{C}(A,X)\simeq *$ for each object $A$. On the other hand, if $\mathcal{C}$ is a stable $\infty$-category equipped with a $t$-structure $\tau$, we have a formally similar notion: for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, there is a functor $\tau_{\leq n}:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}_{\leq n}$ left adjoint to the inclusion, where the notion of truncation is now given by the $t$-structure.

Stable categories and topoi are essentially disjoint, with the only stable $\infty$-topos being trivial. Stable categories can, however, be presentable, and indeed they very often are. Since presentable categories also have a truncation factorization system, the first natural question to ask would be "Does the notion of truncation given by the $t$-structure coincide with the intrinsic notion of truncation in $\mathcal{C}$?" The answer to this question is unfortunately "no". As Lurie remarks in Warning 1.2.1.19 of *Higher Algebra*, the only intrinsically $n$-truncated object of a stable category is a point, regardless of the value of $n$. However, the two notions *do* coincide when we restrict to the connective objects. In fact, this is even true without the assumption of presentability.

My question is about unifying these two forms of factorization. Classically, we can combine the theory of abelian categories with the theory of topoi by considering sheaves of abelian groups (or sheaves valued in some Grothendieck abelian category). The apparent $\infty$-categorical analogue of this would be considering sheaves of spectra on the étale topoi of some topos $\mathcal{X}$. For example, for $\mathcal{X}=\operatorname{Spaces}$, this gives us a stable $\infty$-category which is natural to compare to the topos of parameterized spectra. More generally, we have a topos $T\mathcal{X}$ of "$\mathcal{X}$-parameterized spectra" (aka the tangent topos) and a stable category $\operatorname{Sh}_{\operatorname{Sp}}(\mathcal{X})$. If I'm not mistaken, this latter category comes with a natural $t$-structure induced by the Postnikov $t$-structure on spectra, hence a natural notion of connectivity and truncation that can be compared to the topos-theoretic version in the category of parameterized spectra. How do these compare? I'm particularly interested in the cases where $\mathcal{X}$ is either the topos of a topological space or the topos of nonconnective spectral DM-stacks over a fixed stack.

Comment: Sheaves of spectra are $\infty$-connective when viewed as objects in the tangent $\infty$-topos.

Comment: @MarcHoyois Naturally. But what if we look at the subcategory of sheaves of connective spectra?

Comment: Parametrized connective spectra do not form an $\infty$-topos...

Comment: But if you're willing to look at connective spectra, then it seems to me the unification you're looking for is simply the notion of $n$-truncated object in an $\infty$-category.